# Sage Notebook server post/get

Tags: python, curl, sage

I followed the instructions to install sagenb. Once this was done I ran

```
sage: import sagenb.notebook.notebook_object as nb

sage: nb.notebook(directory="mynotebook")
```

And got my server running. However, I want to be able to SEND data to the server and RECIEVE evaluated data. My users will be sending data from a separate site and I can't have them having to come and log into the sagenb server.

I tried `curl --data x http://localhost:8080/home/admin/0/` and many other commands but I keep getting

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Literally all I want to do is send code to the sage server and have the evaluated code sent back. I've been trying to do this for a few weeks now using sage, django, sagecell, and I just can't get it to work. Maybe it's a configuration problem or maybe I just don't know the correct commands but if anybody could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Or, if anybody has suggestions for something else to use I'm all ears.

Comment: As you know from other answers I've attempted on your questions, I think that sage cell is probably the right way to go.  But here I'm just wondering whether the following question could conceivably be useful to you: http://ask.sagemath.org/question/23431/running-sage-from-other-languages-with-higher-performance/ which seems to be from someone doing something analogous but within PHP instead of Django.  I hope it helps!

Comment: Since the docs at the moment are broken, I'm going to try with a guess: is it an authentication or session cookie problem? Specifically, can you visit `http://localhost:8080/home/admin/0/` without having to log in, with cookies disabled? If not, then you need to figure out some way to force a permanent login session with a known cookie value, and pass the value in your curl command

Comment: And another questions, does that view/page accept POST requests. The error message seems to indicate it doesn't like the POST method. Maybe try `curl http://localhost:8080/home/admin/0?x=x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use the Firefox network monitor. Open a notebook an evaluate en expression. You can then see the HTTP header of the XHR request:
[image]

You can also see the content of the body of the same request:

[image]

As you can see, I've evaluated the expression `max(3,8)`

There is several problems with your curl request.

1. You didn't put the `eval` at the end of the url.
2. You probably have to put a cookie for authentication
3. The data are encoded with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you have to set the `Content-type` accordingly.

Depending on the way the requests are proccessed you maybe also need to set more HTTP header fields.

The curl approach is maybe not the right one, double check if there is no available api.